# How to use overflow auto in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a couple other pages on the website that have no problems with resizing to height using overflow auto.

The thing I have noticed is the pages work fine with one div.  The page that is not working has two or more div and also I have tried it with a container but I still get the vertical and horizontal scroll bars.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="a">
            <div class="left">List Items</div>
            <div class="right">List Items</div>
        </div>
        <div class="b">
            This div is a FORM.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which div has the `overflow` property set? Are the left/right divs floated? Perhaps post your CSS and/or make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)...

Comment: show your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you post the CSS code as well?

Comment: Might help if you included the CSS for this

Comment: I apologize about that.  I have tried many things, floated div left and right, overflow to different items.  I have tried so many things I figured it was time to ask for help.  Here is a fiddle.  It works opened in chrome but not in IE.  http://jsfiddle.net/eASFU/

Comment: @Christian Varga does that fiddle help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made an IE only style sheet and changed the .content to overflow: hidden.  also took the width off of a couple of classes to make the content fit correctly as it does already in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When a css works in other browsers but not in IE9, chance is that your header isn't correct. Check with this one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```